# Jsonp callback function not working? Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, dashcode

So I'm totally new to this, but jsonp seemed so simple, I'm just trying to make a web app using dashcode.  I need to put twitter json data on a page of my web app.  This is what I tried.

I put this code in index.html

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/users/USERNAME.json?callback=handleResponse"/>
```

Then I created a javascript file

```
function handleResponse(responseJson){
alert(responseJson.status.text);
}
```

When I put the javascript file as the datasource I get an error saying it is not valid JSON or XML.  As I said I am new to this, so I might be doing it completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You code works, at least in Chrome, with one small tweak - see http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/jJTQn/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleResponse(responseJson){
    alert(responseJson.status.text);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://twitter.com/users/Pogue.json?callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

The small tweak is closing the `script` tag properly (`script` tags can't be self-closing, for reasons I'm apparently too lazy to Google). Wouldn't hurt to throw `type="text/javascript"` in there too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the handleResponse function is defined before the external jsonp call.

(Also your script tag is invalid)

```
<script>
function handleResponse(responseJson){
  alert(responseJson.status.text);
}
</script>
<script src="http://twitter.com/users/USERNAME.json?callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on “Widget Attributes” in the left-hand source pane. Under “Network / Disk Access”, make sure that “Allow Network Access” is checked. Without this checked your widget won’t be able to make any AJAX requests.